# Default user в windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, users

Добрый день, есть ли что-то типа шаблона профиля default user в винде, в котором можно настроить все параметры ОС и ПО и применить его для создания новых пользователей в домене, либо локальный юзер на пк, который можно заложить в образ? Слышал, что такое было для пользователей на терминалах, там у каждого нового юзера по-дефолту был настроен рабочий стол и проги.

Comment: `C:\Users\Public`?

Answer (score 1):

Мой вопрос решил этот гайд: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2110-customize-default-user-profile-new-accounts-windows-10-a.html

П.С. Экстеншены Google chrome не переносятся, но переносятся автозаполнения форм, история и т.д. Так что осторожней